# Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

OS: Windows 10 x86

### java jdk and jre v:1.8.162

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at 
https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap

---

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU7xk.png)